# exponential = polynomial diophantine equation

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

Let $a$ be a fixed constant like 2 or 3 (for example). Let $P(x)$ be a single variable polynomial in x with integer coefficients.

What is known about the natural number solutions $(x,y)$ of

$$P(x) = a^y$$

can we find a bound $x < B$? Is this a known/named problem?

Comment: It's clear that for large-esque family of polynomials we get infinite family of solutions.
Consider very simple example $P(x) = (x+k)^2$, then clearly we get perfect powers of any integer you like as many times as you like. Looking at this it seems that condition that $P$ is irreducible might come into this at some point.

On the other hand sometimes we have inequalities similar to $x^n < P(x) < (x+1)^n$ leading to some bounds. Perhaps more background to this question would help?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_lifting).  Start with the fact "$P(x) = a^y$" implies "$P(x) \cong 0 \pmod{a^y}$", although keep in mind that the implication does not work in the reverse direction.